# How to retrieve list of layers from dwg file using derivative api or Autodesk.forge library c#

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am working on `Autocad` using C# so need to know whether there is any way to get flat `list` of layers from the `dwg` file (using urn).

Right now I am using "`GetModelviewPropertiesAsync`" method of `Autodesk` library, but this is giving me of hierarchical data and it is not efficient to iterate through each loop.

Also tried this api [Link](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/%7Burn%7D/metadata/%7Bguid%7D/properties). This is also not giving me a flat `list`.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Forge Model Derivative APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/overview) only provide the structured properties. [Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/developers_guide/overview) obtains the layers by traversing through the properties (just once) after loading the urn. Is there any reason why you'd need to traverse the properties in a loop?

Comment: On upload of a CAD file, I am trying to map  the layers in the file with layers in my database. All this without loading the urn in the viewer. So I am looking at an AutoCAD API which can return me a list of layers and its properties simply by giving it the urn. The Model derivative API doesn't seem to return.

Comment: The Model Derivative API only returns the properties in a structured form, but I'm wondering what you meant by "it is not efficient to iterate through each loop". You could run the operation (extracting a flat list of layers from the structured properties) just once, after the CAD file is uploaded, and then store the list somewhere for later reuse.